# How to let a user choose the initial ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I've been searching but I can't seem to figure out what the best way to approach this is.

I would like to allow users to choose an initial ViewController after they've completed onboarding.

Ideally - this would just a UITableViewController in a UINavigationController with the options, and a user can check one and go back.

Clarification: The settings would be "Choose Tab on Launch" segue to list of 3 choices". My VCs are Tabs in a TabBarController, those are the ones I'd like to let the user pick.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Still conceptualizing it - I know I have to do it in AppDelegate, and I would call on this: storyboard.instantiateViewController. But what I don't know is how to store a property that would hold the VC Identifier.

Comment: Is this something where I need to use Persist Data?

Comment: Use a custom tab bar controller subclass and then select the appropriate tab based on a value you have saved in user defaults

Comment: Thanks Paul - UserDefaults is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said, you should use a tab bar controller and user defaults.

For choosing which tab to open on launch, use user defaults:

```
//Get the selection however you wish
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(selectedIndex, forKey: "initialVCIndex")
```

And then on startup

```
if let index = defaults.integer(forKey: "initialVCIndex"){
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index
}else{
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for selecting a specific tab in UITabBarController.

```
let index = 1//index of view controller you want to switch
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I think that one good way to achieve this would be to setup segues between your UITableViewController and all the different View controllers you wish to be able to allow the user to switch to.

Then, as part of the table row data model, store the segue names.

When a user selects a row in the table, retrieve the associated segue name and then perform that segue, which should then display the appropriate view controller to the user.

If you are doing this using a UINavigationController, and have setup push segues to the UIViewControllers  then the user should be able to go back using the Navigation controller, and switch view etc.

The code to perform the segue is fairly simple as so:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "[segue name]", sender: self)
```

I think this approach should allow you to get the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Thanks Malcom - I've clarified my question above. The VCs the user can choose from are VCs in a TabBarController.